# how i can use my bg to my layout in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

when i wanna put my img from drawableto my activity like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"> <-------------------(here)
....
..
</LinearLayout>
```

there is no someting wrong in android studio, but when i run it with emulator, my app cant be opened, its close automatic, so how to put my img to my layout?

and here is log error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.soalmasuk, PID: 3716
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(149107744bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17314)
```

Comment: could you share the error log

Comment: can you show what you have here android:background="@drawable/bg?

Comment: share error log please.

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.soalmasuk, PID: 3716
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(149107744bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17314)`

Comment: try using libraries like picasso and glide, they can help u resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your image is too big and your emulator doesn't have enough memory, try reducing the image size and increasing the memory for your emulator.

In any case, it's not a good practice put big images in the background.